# Partial file memory mapping using File::Map

Tags: perl

Is there a way to do some kind of partial file mapping using the [`File::Map`](http://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aMap) module?

If I write

```
map_file($map, $filename);
```

it tells me that there is not enough memory for this operation.

It seems my files are to large to map them completely into memory.
Can I map them chunk by chunk?

Comment: You're probably running out of address space, not memory. You probably have a 32-bit Perl, which means your entire process must fit in 4GB, and that includes 1 or 2GB reserved by the OS. With a 64-bit Perl, your process is only limited to 64GB. You can map files almost that large even if you don't have that much RAM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~leont/File-Map-0.56/lib/File/Map.pm), yes: map_file can take two optional arguments `$offset` and `$length`

Comment: Shame on me:rtfm, ok. But I would not like to try various length until it'll work. And I think that if I have a working length to do map_file it'll consume all available to perl memory, so there will be no more memory for other variables/operations. I know how to find how many memory is actually used be perl, but not how many RAM is total available to perl - any suggestions? @b0fh

Comment: @bootware: `b0fh` has answered your question very well and I see no reason for your bad manners. Please be grateful to people who voluntarily offer solutions to you.

Comment: sorry, was absend. Thanks @b0fh.

Comment: @Borodin,@ikegami: Under windows this works only for offsets within the range[0..4095]. The File::Map documentation says "$offset and $length are byte positions in the file". The windows function MapViewOfFile takes a Low and a High offset. MS:"The combination of the high and low offsets must specify an offset within the file mapping. They must also match the memory allocation granularity of the system. That is, the offset must be a multiple of the allocation granularity.". How can one use File::Map with higher offset under Windows?

Comment: Please describe what it is you are trying to do. There may be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are mapping a text file then you should use [`Tie::File`](http://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile) instead. It will page the necessary parts of the file in and out of memory as required and you will never hit a limit.

Comment: Normally, memory mapping files is used to speed things up. If that's the goal, Tie::File is the last thing you want.

Comment: @ikegami: I believe it is most often used to allow random access to a file. `Tie::File` does that well, and may well be fast enough for purpose. In any case, much of the speed advantage of mapping a text file is voided by having to read the whole file to find the record boundaries.

Comment: Tie::File does not do that well. Tie::File does that very poorly. For starters, it takes 20x to 30x longer than not using Tie::File.

Comment: @ikegami: That is a gross generalisation whose truth depends on what you are doing to the file contents and what *“not using Tie::File”* means, amongst many other things. I suspect you are suffering from premature optimisation, as I have used the module very many times and have never had a problem with inefficency. If you are avoiding it to save an imaginary couple of milliseconds then you are depriving yourself of an ideal API for many applications, and comments like yours will discourage others who don't know better from using a perfectly good and very useful Perl module.

Comment: @ikegami: I have just realised that you are probably referring to the way `Tie::File` writes to disk every time the tied array is altered. Note that the OP's call to `map_file` accesses the file read-only, so this behaviour is irrelevant. However the file in question may still contain binary data, in which case this exchange is moot.

Comment: We're talking 60s vs 2s just to read a file. That's not premature optimisation.

Comment: Can you back that up? I'm getting between six and seven times longer using `Tie::File` than a simple sequential read for a file with five million lines of 80 characters. Considering the additional functionality it provides I think that's reasonable, and it seems your claim of 30x degradation is misinformation.

Comment: Sure, search SO past questions involving Tie::File. Further proof that it's not just preumature opt. Anyway, 2s vs 12s is still a significant difference.

Comment: @ikegami: Interestingly, just replacing `CORE::readline` with `sub myreadline { return readline $_[0] }` more than halves the performance. It would take a `Tie::File_XS` to do significantly better.